# Vuex state on page refresh and multiple tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my app i use firebase API for users authentication

I save the login status as a boolean value in my vuex state

When the user logs in I set the login status to true and using this I hide the login button on the top menu and display the log out button and vice versa when the user logs out.

So i use [vuex-persisted state](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) to save the state for page refreshes

The dafault storage in **vuex-persisted state** is local storage

Instead of saving the state of store on locaal storage i want it to be saved in cookies...so i followed the same apprach as described in the [vuex-persisted state](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) documentationn

**the problems I am facing are:**

- when i use the default storage i.e local storage it works but when i use cookies the state is not getting saved in the cookie and persisted state does not work
- when i open the app on 2 different tabs and the user logs out in one tab the state is synced in both tabs but log out button is still shown in the other tab

**my store**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'


import authStore from './modules/auth'
import statusStore from './modules/allStatus'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
modules: {
    authStore,
    statusStore
},
plugins: [
     createPersistedState({ 
        getState: (key) => Cookies.getJSON(key), 
        setState: (key, state) => Cookies.set(key, state, { expires: 3, secure: true }) 
     })
]
});
```

Answer (score 12):

The author of `vuex-persistedstate` here.

You've indeed try to set your cookies on a "secure connection". Try to set `secure` to `false` should do the trick. Otherwise open an issue on the repository.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and thought that persisted state cookies were not working. I changed "secure: true" to "secure: false" and it started working as described in the documentation. If you testing the app in a non SSL enabled environment like a localhost nodejs server, try the "secure: false" option.

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap and vue js that works for me!

```
<div id="app">
    <b-tabs content-class="mt-3" v-model="myIndex" @input="change()">
        <b-tab title="Tab 1">
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Tab 2">
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Tab 3">
        </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
</div>

<script>

    let lecture = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data() {
            return {
                myIndex: 0, // Current tab
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            // Get the previous tab from the url
            this.myIndex = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace('#',''), 10);
        },

        methods: {
            change () {
                // Save the current tab in url
                window.location.hash = this.myIndex;
            }

        }
    });

</script>
```