# currentUser not getting set with Vuex

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

I added some code to my vue project so I can save the state of a user - which is whether he is logged in or not. If the state is not null, I want to display the navbar and footer. I added all the vuex import statements. I am using an axios call to the db which returns a json `response`. `response.data` comes back as true/false. If true, I redirect the user to the main page. Then I create a user object called `currentUser`, but I'm not sure what to base it on, so it is getting set to `null`. I need to use the `state` in a few places throughout my app, but it is not getting set. Please someone help. Thanks in advance. (code is below)

User.js:

```js
            import JwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

        export default class User {
          static from (token) {
            try {
              let obj = JwtDecode(token)
              return new User(obj)
            } catch (_) {
              return null
            }
          }

          
              constructor ({username}) {
            this.username = username 
            
          }

        
        }
```

App.vue:

```js
            <template>
          <div id="app">
            <template v-if="currentUser">
              <Navbar></Navbar>
            </template>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <router-view></router-view>
              <template v-if="currentUser">
                <Foot></Foot>
              </template>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>


        <script>
        import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
        import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
        import Foot from '@/components/Foot'

        export default {

        name: 'App',
        components: {
          Navbar,
          Foot
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({ currentUser: 'currentUser' })
          },
```

mutation_types.js:

```js
                        export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN'
                        export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT'
```

auth.js:

```js
            /* global localStorage */

        import User from '@/models/User'
        import * as MutationTypes from './mutation_types'

        const state = {
          user: User.from(localStorage.token)
        }


        const mutations = {
            [MutationTypes.LOGIN] (state) {
              state.user = User.from(localStorage.token)
            },
            [MutationTypes.LOGOUT] (state) {
              state.user = null
            }
          }
          
          const getters = {
            currentUser (state) {
              return state.user
            }
          }
          
          const actions = {
            login ({ commit }) {
              commit(MutationTypes.LOGIN)
            },
          
            logout ({ commit }) {
              commit(MutationTypes.LOGOUT)
            }
          }
          
          export default {
            state,
            mutations,
            getters,
            actions
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user store should only set the default state. AFter making request to validate user. You should use `actions` and `mutations` to set the user state. Call the action via `store.dispatch("user/login", user)` where you return `new User(obj)`.

```js
    let obj = JwtDecode(token)
    const user = new User(obj)
    store.dispatch("user/login", user)
```

```js
    const actions = {
            login ({ commit }, userObject) {
              commit(MutationTypes.LOGIN, userObject)
            },
    
            logout ({ commit }) {
              commit(MutationTypes.LOGOUT)
            }
    }

    const mutations = {
            [MutationTypes.LOGIN] (state, user) {
              state.user = user;
            },
            [MutationTypes.LOGOUT] (state) {
              state.user = null
            }
    }
```

On a other note, you have dumb getters. Meaning they just return the state. You can rather call the user object directly out of state. Use getters when you want to modify the return value before returning it.

Comment: I am new to vuex and don't understand your answer. Can you clarify a bit more how to save the state, and where exactly the changes belong? (in which files)

Comment: I recommend you first go through all of the vuex docs(https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) and the examples(https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples) so you could get more context then I could assist better.

Comment: Ok I went through the documentation and some vuex tutorials. I verify the user in my Login component and then do I dispatch the `login` action from there? Also, I am having trouble creating a JWT token to pass in for `state.user` because my axios call just returns a Json boolean value.... Do you suggest I use `LocalStorage.token` and if yes, please elaborate....

Comment: If the user is logged in successfully you can dispatch a login action. This action will check if the user is valid. You can set create a `attribute` on the login state called `authentication`. And set that to true depending on your login action result.

Axios return a promise so you should you async/await on the axios call. Then return value will be in data.results.

Well some people store the JWT in local storage and other people store it in cookies. I prefer not to store the JWT in the state. But in the state I have a authentication attribute. There is few articles that elaborate on that

Comment: @JeremyWalters-Thanks! I managed to set `state`. Skipped creating the `user ` object. Just dispatched action that called `login` mutation - which set `state.authentication` to `true`. Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090136/vuex-state-on-page-refresh-and%20-multiple-tabs?rq=1) answer to get state to persist with **js-cookie** and **vuex-persistedstate**.

Comment: Cool, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I took a little look and it seems you use '=' instead of Vue.set() to set your state variable.

Refer to the answer : [vuex - is it possible to directly change state, even if not recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122648/vuex-is-it-possible-to-directly-change-state-even-if-not-recommended)

Comment: can you show how I would use Vue.set() with some code?